# SQL Query To Check if an item is available on a specific date range

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have four tables `listing` `transaction` `transaction_item`  `booking`

and these tables look like this

`listing` table

| id | quantity | title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | sony camera |

`transaction` table

| id | customer_id | provider_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

`transaction_item` table

| id | transaction_id | listing_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

`booking` table

| id | transaction_id | start | end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-10-04 | 2022-10-13 |

the intention behind this is, the `provider` can rent their items `listing` to the `customer`

so customer can check availabiltiy of any `listing` before booking

I am writing an SQL query like this to check the availability

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM transaction 
JOIN booking ON booking.transaction_id = transaction.id 
JOIN transaction_item ON transaction_item.transaction_id = transaction.id 
WHERE (transaction_item.listing_id = 1) 
AND 
((booking.start >= '2022-10-04' AND booking.start < '2022-10-13') 
OR 
(booking.end > '2022-10-04' AND booking.end <= '2022-10-13'));
```

this query returns the total number of bookings of a specific `listing` in the particular date range

then I have to compare this value with a specific `listing` quantity if it is less than the quantity then this `listing` is available otherwise not

**so what is your problem and what would like to solve**

my problem is I want to write a query that can tell me if this item is available in the specific date range

i would like to compare `listing.quantity` with `count(*)`

how can i achive or write this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM transaction 
JOIN booking ON booking.transaction_id = transaction.id 
JOIN transaction_item ON transaction_item.transaction_id = transaction.id 
JOIN listing ON listing.id = transaction_item.listing_id
WHERE (transaction_item.listing_id = 1) 
AND 
total < listing.quantity
AND 
((booking.start >= '2022-10-04' AND booking.start < '2022-10-13') 
OR 
(booking.end > '2022-10-04' AND booking.end <= '2022-10-13'));
```

when i run this query i get this error
`column \"total\" does not exist`

thank you so much for your valuable time

Comment: You want `HAVING`: [The WHERE clause specifies conditions on columns in the select list, but cannot refer to aggregate functions. The HAVING clause specifies conditions on groups, typically formed by the GROUP BY clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

Comment: 1) What client are you running this in? 2) Is the field name in the table actually `total` or a mixed/upper case version of it e.g. something like `Total`? As of now the issue is the database cannot find the column name.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver it's a alias for count, table does not have any column name total

Comment: Missed that. At any rate the alias for `count()`(total) is not available in the `WHERE` clause.  As @erik258 pointed out you need to use [Having](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-HAVING).